# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'accountForm' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

Hello I am trying to have the user enter a value in a for. I am taking an input from a jsp file as follows:

```
    <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/account/deposit" class="form" modelAttribute="accountForm" role="form">

        <div class="form-group">
            <form:label path="balance">Deposit</form:label>
            <form:input path="balance" class="form-control" />
            <form:errors cssClass="error" path="balance"></form:errors>
        </div>

        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Deposit</button>
        </div>

    </form:form>
```

The controller I implemented is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deposit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postAccountPage(@ModelAttribute("accountForm") @Valid AccountForm accountForm, BindingResult result) {
            if(result.hasErrors()){
        logger.info("ERROR: "+ result.toString());
        return "account";
    }
    double newBalance = accountForm.getBalance();
    //Member member = memberService.getCurrentMember();
    //Account account = accountRepository.findByAccountNumber(member.getAccountNumber());
    //double newBalance = account.getBalance() - accountForm.getBalance();

    //logger.info(Double.toString(accountForm.getBalance()));
    logger.info(Double.toString(newBalance));

    return "redirect:/account";
}
```

and the AccountForm constructer is:

```
public AccountForm(String accountNumber, String accountType, double balance) {
    super();
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    this.accountType = accountType;
    this.balance = balance;
}
```

With getters and setters.

I get an ERROR: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'accountForm' available as request attribute. As well I am getting a Request method 'POST' not supported Error. Not sure what I am doing wrong and have looked all over the web(This site included). Thanks.

Comment: Can you try changing `@ModelAttribute("AccountForm")` to `@ModelAttribute("accountForm")` (notice the small `a`) ?

Comment: Also add `method="post"` to your form

Comment: Awesome it worked. I believe it was only method="post" since another controller had the correct ModelAttribute(small a).

Comment: Great, I have added it as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things:

- change @ModelAttribute("AccountForm") to @ModelAttribute("accountForm") (notice the small a)
- add method="post" to the form